# Queuing up of threads because of timer in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

In my app I am using threads. So I have a function called pull which runs in a separate thread.

```
var timerCall = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   _subscription = timerCall.Subscribe(async res =>
        {
            List<dynamic> result = pull();

            if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
                await Connection.Broadcast(new
                {
                    id = _newestId,
                    events = result
                });
        });
```

Every second I call the thread. I am using lock there as well in my pull function like this

```
lock (_locker){
       // do stuff 
}
```

Lets assume the function pull takes on average 1.2 seconds per call, so this means that in the end I would end up having a large queue. I don't need that. Any ways to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing I can think of. You can use the [Monitor Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the lock is acquired. So you can skip the thread if it's still busy and wait another second till the other thread is done.

Comment: So should I do something like Moniter.TryEnter(){} instead of lock(_locker) ?

Comment: Yes, it will return true if it acquired the lock. Do the code inside that if block. So it will skip it if another thread is already using the lock, so you won't get a huge queue

Comment: Also, I would use this in the thread itself or if you do it in the pull method, return null.

Comment: `if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locker)) 
{ 
//do normal code that returns the list
}
else
{
return null;
}`